# UPDATE error: "Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of REPLACE"

Tags: sql-server

Why do I get this error from my query?

> Msg 8116, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
>   Argument data type text is invalid for argument 1 of replace function.

Query:

```
UPDATE 
    tableName
SET
    fieldName = REPLACE (fieldName, '&lt;', '<')
WHERE
    id = 100
```

Comment: `ntext`, `text`, and `image` data types will be removed in a future version of SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use them. Use `nvarchar(max)`, `varchar(max)`, and `varbinary(max)` instead. [See details here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993.aspx). `TEXT` is a really horribly bad datatype - there are so many things you **cannot** do to it (you cannot use all the string functions, for one) - stop using it - NOW!

Comment: @marc_s sometimes it's not a choice.. e.g. for me I have to import data from Excel with cells having over 255 characters, and that is passed on as ntext type by ACE OLE DB provider.

Comment: @Uttam: maybe you need to use it *temporarily* during import - OK, maybe so. But my point is: **do not STORE it** permanently in your actual data tables in SQL Server in such a deprecated datatype which causes you nothing but headaches and grief.

Comment: @marc_s yes, totally agree.. no ntext, text data types used in any of my tables.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Try this:

```
UPDATE tableName
SET fieldName = REPLACE (CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), fieldName), '&lt;', '<')
WHERE id = 100
```

Comment: Both answers fix the problem but they don't mention the reason (look at marc's comment). Also, the error message itself tells the reason.

Answer (score 3):

this will work for you

```
UPDATE yourTableName
SET 
fieldName = REPLACE (CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX), fieldName), '&lt;', '<')
WHERE id = 100
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make the same operation for Text bigger than 8000 character you can use the code below:

```
DECLARE @v VARCHAR(10) -- TEXT TO ADD
DECLARE @Vs VARHCAR(10) -- TEXT TO FIND
SET @v = 'String text to add'
SET @Vs = 'String text to find'


       UPDATE 
                yourTableName
        SET 
                textField = SUBSTRING(textField,1,DATALENGTH (textField)-LEN(@Vs)) + REPLACE( CAST(SUBSTRING(textField,DATALENGTH(textField)-LEN(@Vs)-1,DATALENGTH (textField)) AS VARCHAR(4)),@Vs,@v )
            WHERE 
                yourTableName.id = @iRifID -- Update for Table ID
```